# Regex - Validate an account number with two different patterns

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate an account number. 
A valid number could be either a sequence of exactly **11** digits or 3 groups of digits separated by hyphens (2 digits  **-**  3 digits  **-** 6 digits)

I tried this :

```
/^([0-9]{11})|([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6})$/
```

But it only works for the second rule . The first rule doesn't work as it allows numbers of more than 11 digits

This is how I use the regex in my js function :

```
 var re = /^([0-9]{11})|([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6})$/;
         if (re.test(txtNumber.value)==true) {
             return 1;
         }
         else {
             alert("Invalid Account Number");
             return 0;
         }
```

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated

**VALID NUMBERS:**

12345678912 (11 digits)

12-345-678912 (11 digits separated by hyphens)

**INVALID NUMBERS:**

1223 (less than 11 digits)

111111111111 ( more than 11 digits)

123-23-678912 (**11 digits** , but not separated correctly, it should be 2 digits-3 digits-6 digits)

Comment: It is not a duplicate since I'm not asking how to validate a number with the XX-XXX-XXXXXX pattern. What I'm asking is why only one of the rules in my regex works and the other doesn't.

Comment: Still it's good information for future users who see this question, so I'll leave it. You're not in danger of having this closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `|` regex operator precedence is the lowest, it should be written like this:

```
/^(?:[0-9]{11}|[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6})$/
```

... so that alternation pattern is bound both to the beginning and the end of the string.

As it stands in your code, pattern checks for either sequence of 11 digits *at the beginning of the string*, or sequence of 'two digits, hyphen, three digits, hyphen, six digits' *at its end* - but never really bind the rule to both ends. And that's easy to prove:

```
var patt = /^([0-9]{11})|([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6})$/;
patt.test('acdbdfdsfsf22-333-666666'); // true
```

As a sidenote, as you don't need to capture anything with that grouping expression, I've prepended it with `?:`. Actually, it can be optimized even more:

```
/^[0-9]{2}(?:[0-9]{9}|-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6})$/
```

... as the less you alternate, the better. But in this case it really won't matter much, I suppose.

---

In short, the problem can be illustrated with these two patterns:

```
/^a|b$/
```

This reads as 'match either `a at the beginning of the string`, or `b at its end`.

```
/^(?:a|b)$/
```

This reads as 'match the `beginning of the string`, followed by either `a` or `b`, followed by `the end of the string`'.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it well :( A valid number could a sequence of 11 digits (123456789123)  OR a sequence of 'two digits, hyphen, three digits, hyphen, six digits (12-123-123456)

Comment: How that contradicts what I said? Check the example in my answer: none of your rules given are actually strict enough, as they (because of `|` precedence) are not applied to the whole string.

Comment: My bad. It should be '12345678912'

Comment: What do I need to do to make those two rules apply to the whole string, not only to the begging or end of it.

Comment: @eddy Have you actually tested the pattern?

Comment: Yes I tried this one /^[0-9]{2}(?:[0-9]{9}|-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6})$/ , but it allows more than 11 digits :(

Comment: I'm sorry, but - no, it doesn't. Play with this pattern [here](http://regex101.com/r/jK1vO4).

Comment: Please check my question. I added examples of valid and invalid numbers.

Comment: Which of those invalid numbers pass the test with the pattern given in this answer? Which of those valid numbers do not pass this test?