# only numeric numbers with control

Tags: java, string, integer

Firstly I'm a new person here. I need to ask one question.

```
Scanner klavye = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("DDD-DD-DDDD enter bank number digit: ");
String hesapNo = klavye.nextLine();

if(hesapNo.length() != 11) {
   System.out.println("You need to enter number with 11 digit");
}
else {
   if(hesapNo.charAt(3) == '-' && hesapNo.charAt(6) == '-') {
       System.out.println(hesapNo + " is valid");
   }
   else {
      System.out.println(hesapNo + " is not valid");
   }
}
```

I want to take only digit number but If I write below like this:
ABC-DC-SMND 
"The count is valid" 
how can I solve this problem?

Thanks for all of your interest.

Comment: I think this is a good opportunity to learn *regular expressions*.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749891/regex-validate-an-account-number-with-two-different-patterns

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with regular expressions and a loop to prompt the user until a valid input.

```
Scanner klavye = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("DDD-DD-DDDD enter bank number digit: ");
String hesapNo;
final String regexPattern = "\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}";
do {
   hesapNo = klavye.nextLine();
   System.out.println("You need to enter a number with 11 digit with pattern: DDD-DD-DDDD");
}
while(!hesapNo.matches(regexPattern));

System.out.println(hesapNo + " is valid");
```

Answer (score 1):

That can be done with a simple [regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) using [`String.matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-):

```
Scanner klavye = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("DDD-DD-DDDD enter bank number digit: ");
String hesapNo = klavye.nextLine();

if(hesapNo.matches("\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}")){ // <-- this regex matches your pattern DDD-DD-DDDD
    System.out.println(hesapNo + " is valid");
}else{
    System.out.println("You need to enter number with 11 digit");
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to keep asking for input until a valid one is entered then you can do this:

```
Scanner klavye = new Scanner(System.in);
String hesapNo;
boolean validInput;

System.out.println("DDD-DD-DDDD enter bank number digit: ");
do {
    hesapNo = klavye.nextLine();
    validInput = hesapNo.matches("\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}");
    if (!validInput) { // if invalid input then warn the user
        System.out.println("Your bank number must be in DDD-DD-DDDD format");
    }
} while (!validInput); // loop until a valid input is provided
System.out.println(hesapNo + " is valid");
```